# How to create a secure Access to a RestAPI of a (WPF)-Application

Tags: c#, php, wpf, security, authentication

I'm trying to create an application (in c# WPF) which should communicate with a RESTApi.
I want to create the RESTApi by myself.

So at the moment I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to let the user of my c# application, logon to the RESTApi so he can receive data of the database.

My first thought was Basic Authentication. After some research I realized that i really don't want to pass a password in plaintext (Even if I use SSL).
I'm aware of the importance of salts and I know the best way would be, to use Hash methods which already provides random salts.

But in my specific case I thought about saving a hash in my database with a specific salt using the blowfish algorithm.
Next I would implement a logic which will provide a combination of a salt, like
a combination of username, some pepper,salt and the actual hashed password. Maybe even a sequence which i could build into this logic. Which would be hard to implement if I want to use the Application on different computers, because I have to remember the last sequence.
Anyways, both the RESTApi and my WPF-application would know this logic to create a hash which would be different each time I call the logic (due to the sequence).
So i could match the outcome every time I use the logic.

Basically I did some research about Hashing algorithms. I found BCrypt for both C# and PHP. I already achieved to create Hashs of a password which the user will type in my WPF application. On the other side i used crypt() on my website to create a blowfish hash. Both matched perfectly (using the same salt).

My thoughts were: How can I pass a hashed password to my RESTApi without storing/pass passwords in plaintext.

So my basic question is: 
Is there any better way? Am I on the right track to create a halfway secure "logic". Or is it enough to use Baisc/Digest Authentication if I use SSL?

I know that Security is a very hard thing to achieve but I really want to learn how I can implement such things.

Comment: Whatever you send over the line _is_ a password, whether it is a hash or not. Assuming a man-in-the-middle sees the password, he has what he needs to access your API, so hashing it client-side does not add any security.

Comment: I thought if I use a sequence on the client-side and on the server-side it would be much harder to tell what the next valid hash should be. (Without knowing the sequence logic and it's implementation in the hash)